# Single Server Multiple clients without VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh, vmware

I'm new to server configuration. We have a Dell T630 server. it come with the Vmware. while using multiple VM at the same time i cant able to get the good performance. so i have installed ubuntu directly in the server now i have a good increase in performance. but If multiple people want to use the same Ubuntu at the same time with graphical user interface like vmware is it is possible in ubuntu server. if yes can any one help me with this.

I know how to connect multiple clients using ssh protocol with my server (ssh username@172.17.4.1). but if my clients needs Graphical user interface. example single server for multiple clients max of 3 members at the same time.

Comment: You could try `x2go`, but I think it does not support 3D stuff.

Comment: @Thomas x2go i tried but only one user can use GUI other users cant use the GUI.